# Why $ D_n$ is not simple ?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Why $D_n$ is  not simple ?

i was  asking  this  question  to my professor  . My professor  said me that  $D_n$  is not simple  because  subgroup genereated by $< \frac{R_{360}}{n}>$ is  normal in $D_n$.

Actually  i didn't  understand the  meaning

Any hints/solution  will be appreciated

thanks u

Comment: Are you know about rotations?

Comment: not  so  much  @ChinnapparajR

Comment: do you understand what $D_n$ is?

Comment: @jasmine Well, then perhaps it'd be a good idea for you to first read a little about the nice, intuition-bursting geometrical meaning of dihedral groups. Once you do this it is very likely that you'll  understand better.

Comment: This should help : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2205865/some-subgroup-of-dihedral-group-is-normal