# Proving that subgroup of Rotations in $D_{2n}$ is a normal subgroup

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, dihedral-groups

[image]

I am trying to prove that the group of rotations in $D_{2n}$ is a normal subgroup.

I know this group has a cardinality $n$, and the ratio of the $D_{2n}$ and $R$ is $2.$

I am trying to construct a homomorphism that sends $<R>$, generator group of rotations to an identity element...

Any clues?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Some Subgroup of Dihedral Group is Normal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2205865/some-subgroup-of-dihedral-group-is-normal)

Comment: thank you very much yes I have seen these posts and i am aware that subgroup of index 2 is normal, i would like to prove it using a homomorphism to kernel..

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you've noted, $|D_{2n}|/|K|=2$, and so $[D_{2n}:K]=2$ which implies $K$ is normal: see [Subgroup of index 2 is Normal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84632/subgroup-of-index-2-is-normal).